merging numpy arrays converts int to decimal
I am need to merge 2 arrays together
so if
a = [] 

and
b is array([76522, 82096], dtype=int64)

the merge will be [76522, 82096]
but i am getting this in a form of decimal
array([76522., 82096.])

here is my code
a = np.concatenate((a, b))

how can i merge both arrays with same datatype?

Do you need to convert the lists to a numpy array? Why not just a + b to concatenate the lists?

I can't reproduce this. When I try your code I get array([ 3, 98,  4, 78, 12, 45,  9, 39])

@Barmar I get this error when i try a + b
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (2,)

@Barmar the problem i get when a is [] and b  is array([76522, 82096], dtype=int64)

your initial values of a and b are lists, not numpy arrays, that shouldn't happen.

Clearly, that's not how you are creating your arrays, because your creation is causing at least one of the arrays to be datatype float.  It's very easy to convert it back to integer.  Show us your real code.

A concatenate with [] suggests  you are starting a loop, much like the alist.append(....) way of growing a list.  That is a poor imitation.  Arrays don't grow as effortlessly as lists.

Since a is empty, when it gets converted to a numpy array, it chooses a default dtype=float64. Do the conversion explicitly so you can specify the dtype.
np.concatenate((np.array(a, dtype=np.int64), b))


works many  thanks
